# {"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 0, "_z": null} React Native when DataStore.Save

Tags: javascript, react-native, aws-amplify, datastore

when I open the Basket
console.log(basketDish.Dish) get result like {"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 0, "_z": null}.

I think DataStore.Save doesn't wait until Dish get dish.

How can I solve it?

```
const addDishToBasket = async (dish, quantity) => {
    console.log("add dish to basket", dish, quantity);
    console.log("type of dish", typeof(dish))

    let theBasket = basket || (await createNewBasket());
    console.log("theBasket.id",theBasket.id)
    

    const newDish = await DataStore.save(
      new BasketDish({ 
        quantity: quantity,
        Dish : dish,
        basketID: theBasket.id
      })
    );
    console.log("BasketDish", BasketDish)
    console.log("newDish", newDish)
    setBasketDishes([...basketDishes, newDish]);
  };
```

```
add dish to basket {"_deleted": null, "_lastChangedAt": 1670763723808, "_version": 2, "createdAt": "2022-12-04T04:32:38.301Z", "description": "Double meat, gouda cheese, cheddar cheese, cooked ham, bacon, egg, salad and rustic potatoes.", "id": "4d2b8d8f-0ed2-414c-b23b-9570fe77b030", "image": "https://notjustdev-dummy.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uber-eats/restaurant3.jpeg", "name": "Hamburger La Super Cabo Burger", "price": 8.9, "restaurantID": "f5cdaf6c-64f7-4cbc-bdb2-19fcace7f65f", "updatedAt": "2022-12-11T13:02:03.761Z"} 5
 LOG  type of dish object
 LOG  theBasket.id f22a7ab3-6a27-441e-9967-adb2646c1867
 LOG  BasketDish [Function BasketDish]
 LOG  newDish {"_deleted": undefined, "_lastChangedAt": undefined, "_version": undefined, "basketDishDishId": "4d2b8d8f-0ed2-414c-b23b-9570fe77b030", "basketID": "f22a7ab3-6a27-441e-9967-adb2646c1867", "id": "b923a6e7-ff8c-45f5-aeb2-39675afc5343", "quantity": 5}
```

I tried hard but couldn't get result